# What is OE+ in Linux?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

***What is the meaning of `(OE+)` in the following?***

```
$ sudo cat /proc/modules | grep hello //hello_world is a kernel module created by me.
hello_world 20480 1 - Loading 0xffffffffc0221000 (OE+)
```

Here is my situation. 
I have patched the Linux kernel function `load_module()`, which is called from `finit_module()`, the system call used by `insmod` to insert kernel modules.
The patch looks for a specific module, created by me (called `hello_world`) being installed, and when it does, it prevents the call to `do_init_module()`, and returns 0 instead. `do_init_call()` is responsible for calling a module's `init` function, and setting the module state to live (`MODULE_STATE_LIVE`).

When I read `/proc/modules`, the module state is `Loading`, which is expected. I do not understand however the meaning of `(OE+)` at the end of output. This is not displayed against any other module, as is verified by the following command.

```
$ sudo cat /proc/modules | grep OE
hello_world 20480 1 - Loading 0xffffffffc0221000 (OE+)
```

I am using Linux kernel `v4.7.3`.

**Update**

All this is happening in a Qemu virtual machine. On the host, which is running `Linux 4.4.0-36-generic (Ubuntu)`, I get the following.

```
$ sudo cat /proc/modules | grep OE
vboxpci 24576 0 - Live 0xffffffffc082a000 (OE)
vboxnetadp 28672 0 - Live 0xffffffffc066e000 (OE)
vboxnetflt 28672 0 - Live 0xffffffffc0635000 (OE)
vboxdrv 454656 3 vboxpci,vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt, Live 0xffffffffc0783000 (OE)
sep4_0 671744 0 - Live 0xffffffffc06de000 (OE)
socperf2_0 36864 1 sep4_0, Live 0xffffffffc0660000 (OE)
pax 16384 0 - Live 0xffffffffc05f9000 (OE)
```

Comment: You are aware that `/proc` is a pseudo file system, and you can search kernel source code for this string, right?

Comment: Yes, I followed @Aleksey's answer and was able to reach the correct part of the kernel source.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`O` means Out-of-tree module has been loaded.
`E` means Unsigned module has been loaded.
`+` means that the module is being loaded.
`-` means that the module is being unloaded.

The source code for [print_modules()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/module.c?v=4.7#L4171), then [module_flags()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/module.c?v=4.7#L3959), and then [print_tainted()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/panic.c?v=4.7#L315) functions may be helpful in figuring out the meaning of these and some other flags. Take a look at the comment just above `print_tainted()` function. Hope this helps.

Comment: Tx,from the file- 
`P -Proprietary module has been loaded
F -Module has been forcibly loaded
S -SMP with CPUs not designed for SMP
R -User forced a module unload
M -System experienced a machine check exception
B -System has hit bad_page
U -Userspace-defined naughtiness
D -Kernel has oopsed before
A -ACPI table overridden
W -Taint on warning
C -modules from drivers/staging are loaded
I -Working around severe firmware bug
O -Out-of-tree module has been loaded
E -Unsigned module has been loaded
L -A soft lockup has previously occurred
K -Kernel has been live patched`

Comment: Following your answer I found the whole table in <Linux source>/kernel/panic.c